# laravel 5.4 Auth::user() return Null value in Routes web.php file

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

I have tried to access Auth::user() object in group function in Web.php file but it return null value. PLease look my code of web.php file.

```
 Auth::routes();  
    Route::group(['domain' => 'local.proaisys.com','middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
        //dd(\Auth::check());
        dd(Auth::user());
        Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@crm');

    });
```

[image]

Comment: what's the result of `Auth::check()`?

Comment: @Wreigh it show false result.

Comment: I think anything about Auth is not yet processed at that point?

Comment: If user is null, and check says false, there is no user logged in, right?  What is the problem? :-)

Comment: @Don'tPanic  User is logged in but not able fetch user details using Auth::user().

Comment: If `Auth::check()` shows false, no user is logged in.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Once I logged in using my email and password and then I am checking this one which I am getting this so user is already logged in in system.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve here!!

This is you `routes/web.php` file. You need to pass your query inside function, not outside that. How will route know that you need user inside route!!

Try this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'local.proaisys.com','middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
    //dd(\Auth::check());

    Route::get('/dashboard',function() {
        dd(Auth::user());
//Now goto your domain.com/dashboard  your will get user
    });

});
```

Or you can get `dd(Auth::user())` in your function `DashboardController@crm`
You need to give some route in which you want, but you are trying to access it from outside of function.

Hope it helps...Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Try to login your account.
Then try to check again.
if Auth::user() returns null again.
try to check this link
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authuser-returns-null-in-laravel-52

Answer (score 0):

If you have primary key in your `users` table, named other than `id` then it may cause this problem.

The primary key in `users` table should be named as `id` (case-sensitive).

Comment: As It is id only primary key in DB

Comment: Its difficult to understand with the information posted. Can you post more code/explanation, i.e. Users model class, your table structure, login code etc ?